# Date format different for two calls using Orika mapper

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, datamapper, orika

I am getting different date formats for two web-service calls using same mapper.

> By mapper I mean, `map:162, ConfigurableMapper (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)`

The OTB call to get orders i.e. `OrdersController#getOrderForUserByCode()` is showing the date as `"date": "2018-12-22T20:42:31+0000"`.
My custom call to get orders i.e. `IndReportController#createAdvancedOrderSearchReport()` is showing the same date as `"date": 1545511351000`
I am using the same code as OTB to print `OrderWsDTO` i.e. 
`getDataMapper().map(orderData, OrderWsDTO.class, fields)`.
Interestingly, the stack trace of both the calls are also same.
***Stacktrace***:

```
setDate:186, PaymentTransactionEntryWsDTO (de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.order)
mapAtoB:-1, Orika_PaymentTransactionEntryWsDTO_PaymentTransactionEntryData_Mapper103355414120758$116 (ma.glasnost.orika.generated)
map:77, UseCustomMapperStrategy (ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy)
map:254, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapElement:797, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAsCollection:621, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAsList:427, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAtoB:-1, Orika_PaymentTransactionWsDTO_PaymentTransactionData_Mapper103354376799488$70 (ma.glasnost.orika.generated)
map:77, UseCustomMapperStrategy (ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy)
map:254, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapElement:797, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAsCollection:621, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAsList:427, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
mapAtoB:-1, Orika_OrderWsDTO_OrderData_Mapper103352769949289$41 (ma.glasnost.orika.generated)
map:77, UseCustomMapperStrategy (ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy)
map:671, MapperFacadeImpl (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
map:162, ConfigurableMapper (ma.glasnost.orika.impl)
map:211, DefaultDataMapper (de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl)
getOrder:100, OrdersController (com.myproject.core.v2.controller)
```

Please suggest how can I get the OTB date format in my custom call.