# DefaultSessionCloseStrategy

Tags: session, session-state, sap-commerce-cloud

Below Hybris OOTB Strategy is extended by Custom Session Close Strategy so when the session is closed/ session is logout then it should be executed.

```
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DefaultSessionCloseStrategy.DefaultSessionCloseStrategy
```

Custom Strategy is being executed at single server(Developer Machine); whereas, it fails at multiple node servers.

This below session time out has been set as 1800 so it should be executed but its not being executed at multiple node servers(Google GCP clouds).

**default.session.timeout=1800**

Do we need to do extra configuration to make SessionCloseStrategy execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The property `default.session.timeout` is only read in

> hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DefaultSessionCloseStrategy#setTimeoutOnHttpSessionCreation()

So, unless you are manually reading it is a custom overridden class the default behavior should be executed. This time is in *milli seconds*.
You can also check if the property file is same for all the nodes. To be sure go to -

> https://[your node]/hac/platform/config

and search for the property : `default.session.timeout` and check the value.

Also, check if the session timeout on your node is happening in `86400 milliseconds` because this is the default value for timeout if the property `default.session.timeout`is not read.

Comment: Thanks @Farrukh, I verified at all the nodes we set to 1800 ms but the custom close session strategy is not getting executed even if i logged out of session at the storefront.

Comment: @user3691164 : Can you add the spring.xml entries of your bean in the question. You can replace your project name with `customproject`.

Comment: <alias alias="sessionCloseStrategy" name="customSessionCloseStrategy"/>
<bean id="customSessionCloseStrategy" parent="defaultSessionCloseStrategy" class="my.project.session.CustomSessionCloseStrategy">
 </bean>

Comment: you can see the bean definiton above but i couldn't understand how do you meant that replace project name with customproject. I think we have to redefine it as [If ABC is project] : <alias alias="sessionCloseStrategy" name="aBCSessionCloseStrategy"/> <bean id="aBCSessionCloseStrategy" parent="defaultSessionCloseStrategy" class="my.project.session.ABCSessionCloseStrategy"> </bean> –

Comment: @user3691164 : I was just a suggestion that you can replace you project name with abc or something.....
The bean definition looks correct. I think it might have something to do with the context in which the bean is overridden. I am also facing this issue with one of the OTB beans.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141817/change-date-format-in-dto-json-on-returning-through-responsebody

Answer (score 0):

Create [extension].session.timeout in project.properties. And assign some value in seconds. This way you dont need to use the global session timeout (default.session.timeout)